# Round to the closest .25

Tags: t-sql

Does anyone know of a way to round to the closest .25 in t-sql?  Currently I am rounding down using

```
floor(value * 4)/4
```

My client is changing their algorithm and wants to do a midpoint round to the closest quarter.  If the value is less than .125 round to 0.00, if the value is greater than or equal to .125 round up to .25.

Comment: FLOOR([value] / 0.25 + 0.5 ) * 0.25

Answer (score 22, accepted):

use `ROUND(value/25, 2) * 25` like this:

**Example1:**

```
DECLARE @value DECIMAL(18, 2)
SET @value = 1.126
SELECT CAST(ROUND(@value/25, 2) * 25 as numeric(18,2)) AS rounded_val
```

**Output:**

```
1.25
```

**Example2:**

```
DECLARE @value DECIMAL(18, 2)
SET @value = 1.124
SELECT CAST(ROUND(@value/25, 2) * 25 as numeric(18,2)) AS rounded_val
```

**Output:**

```
1.00
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select Sample,
  Round( ( Sample + Sign( Sample ) * 0.125 ) * 4, 0, 1 ) / 4.0 as Rounded
  from ( values ( 0.0 ), ( 0.1 ), ( 1.125 ), ( 0.25 ), ( 10.5 ),
    ( -0.75 ), ( -0.875 ), ( -1.12 ), ( -1.125 ) )
    as Samples( Sample )
```

Note that `ROUND` can be used to truncate the fractional part of a value regardless of the sign. `FLOOR` will always return a value equal to *or less than* the original value, which can be problematic when the value is negative.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to round to an arbitrary precision & rounding strategy.

**rounding to *.25**

```
DECLARE @roundamt DECIMAL(16,2) = .25, @value DECIMAL(18, 2) = 1.7688
SELECT  ROUND(  (@value - FLOOR(@value)) / @roundamt, 0 ) * @roundamt + FLOOR(@value)
```

-- result = 1.750000

**different rounding strategies like 0.02, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75**

```
SELECT
    x.roundamt, ROUND(  (@value - FLOOR(@value)) / roundamt, 0 ) * roundamt + FLOOR(@value)
FROM   
    ( VALUES (0.02), (0.25), (0.5), (0.75) )x(roundamt)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who need to find the closest divider without a remainder you can use:

```
SELECT (CAST(ROUND(@value / 0.25, 2) as int)) * 0.25
```

So basically this will round down to the closest multiple of 0.25